# What does 'gymnast' mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

I came across this word in South Park,S04E12,20mins18secs.
The context is

> I'm as gay as a **gymnast** on shore leave.

I'm sorry that this sentence might be some offensive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means "gymnast" (as in "someone who does *gymnastics*").  Apparently the writers of South Park want to imply that gymnasts are often homosexual, or just perhaps they want to evoke an image of a homosexual gymnast involved in wild sexual contortions.

However it's a mixed metaphor.  The quote is based on the stereotype of ["spending like a **sailor** on shore leave"](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spend+like+a+sailor+on+shore+leave).  Sailors live many months at sea with no entertainment, and no one but each other for company, so when they put into a port they are notoriously extravagant.  This extends to the idea that sailors are often *promiscuous* when on shore leave (although not necessarily homosexual promiscuity).

Note that South Park is famous for its provocative humor.  Compared with some of their other stuff, this one is relatively tame.